# What do the Function keys after F12 do?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, function-keys

While looking at a keyboard remapping program, I saw that one can remap keys from <kbd>F13</kbd> to <kbd>F24</kbd> as well. What do those keys do?

Comment: This will depend on the computer and the operating system

Comment: @Valay_17 no the multimedia keys are completely different and has separate scan codes from F13-F24. It's just that no one uses F13-F24 so many keyboards put some special functions to the function keys when pressing with Fn. And it's not even standardized, each keyboard with have the play button at a different position

Comment: @phuclv Extremely sorry, Thank You for clearing my misconception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They dont do anything, but can do anything.

Function keys are soft keys.  Basically, their functionality is based on whatever program is running.  For example, you might press <kbd>F2</kbd> when you turn your computer on to go into BIOS.  However, once Windows loads, hitting <kbd>F2</kbd> will rename the current file if you are the File Explorer, or rename the currently selected desktop icon.  However, you might launch a program and the <kbd>F2</kbd> saves the file you are working on in that program.

Keyboards with [24 function keys](https://www.google.com/search?q=keyboard%20with%2024%20function%20keys&sxsrf=ALeKk01w8bHmL5NAaqqsoP6e10e6iaz0_w:1585546312505&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjyiO2lvMHoAhX7lnIEHZJsAX8Q_AUoAXoECA0QAw&biw=1280&bih=574), <kbd>F13</kbd> through <kbd>F24</kbd> do exist, but are extremely rare.  Since those keyboards are not common, programmers typically do not assign any functionality those keys.  Since no one is likely to have keyboards with them, why would they?  More than likely, the programmers themselves dont even know these keyboards even exist.  However, since they do, the functionality to use them is available, like in your keyboard remapping program.

Comment: Some keyboards use these for macro keys, which makes things a little easier for remapping without bespoke software

Comment: “Most programmers don’t even know they exist” is true for sure, hardly 0.01% of all programmers might know about this.  ￼

Comment: I think I've seen some keyboards have manufacturer-provided "feature" keys (you know, the kind for adjusting display, audio, etc.) which are just mapped to some unused code in the F[13-24] range instead of their own dedicated event code.

Comment: @user1686  That is incorrect.  Those keys are actually standardized, each generating their own unique scan code.  They are not mapped to anything else, by default.  If they werent unique, then you would have potential conflicts of functionality.

Comment: The F13-F24 are actually commonly used by mainframe users. While the comany where I work operates a mainframe, I see most users with a regular keyboard and just using the `shift` key to access F13-F24.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is googling for help, the F16 key has a use in Excel (clears the current field).

Took me too long to figure out that my Windows stay awake function (which pressed F16 because I believed statements like the above, i.e. that they have no function) would clear the current cell every 30 seconds.